# Passing List to IAM Group Policy Template file

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws

I am creating policy based on tags. The environment value differs for each resource, so I have to add them as multiple values. Unable to pass as list. Tried join,split and for loop. None of them works. Pls help. Below code just add the value as "beta,test" which will not work as expected

**main.tf**

```
locals{
    workspaceValues = terraform.workspace == "dev" ? ["alpha", "dev"] : terraform.workspace == "test" ? ["beta", "test"] : ["prod", "staging"]
}

resource "aws_iam_group_policy" "inline_policy" {
  name   = "${terraform.workspace}_policy"
  group  = aws_iam_group.backend_admin.name
  policy = templatefile("policy.tpl", { env = join(",", local.workspaceValues), region = "${data.aws_region.current.name}", account_id = "${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}" })
}
```

**policy.tpl:**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:*",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "ForAllValues:StringLikeIfExists": {
                    "aws:ResourceTag/Environment": "${env}"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What error do you see when you try this? As far as I can tell you are providing two variables to `templatefile` function (`region`, `account_id`) and you are not using them anywhere in the policy.

Comment: @MarkoE It doesnt throw error. It is added as "beta,test" which will not work as expected. region account id is unused. I agree

Comment: Well, which workspace are you currently working in?

Comment: "beta,test" which will not work as expected" - what exactly do you expect? Do you know the correct value you want to obtained?

Comment: ["beta","test"] this shud be the actual value

Comment: Well, don't use join then. :) Just leave the value as is. ;)

Comment: List will not be accepted in place of string. That will throw error.  on iam.tf line 8, in resource "aws_iam_group_policy" "inline_policy":
│    8:   policy = templatefile("policy.tpl", { env = local.workspaceValues })
│     ├────────────────
│     │ local.workspaceValues is tuple with 2 elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [jsonencode](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/jsonencode) to properly format TF list as a list in json in your template:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:*",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "ForAllValues:StringLikeIfExists": {
                    "aws:ResourceTag/Environment": ${jsonencode(env)}
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

For that you would call the template as follows:

```
resource "aws_iam_group_policy" "inline_policy" {
  name   = "${terraform.workspace}_policy"
  group  = aws_iam_group.backend_admin.name
  policy = templatefile("policy.tpl", { 
                        env = local.workspaceValues
                       })
}
```

You are not using `region` nor `account_id` in your template, so there is no reason to pass them in.

Comment: Jsonencode will throw below error. Error: "policy" contains an invalid JSON: invalid character 'b' after object key:value pair
│ 
│   with aws_iam_group_policy.inline_policy,
│   on iam.tf line 8, in resource "aws_iam_group_policy" "inline_policy":
│    8:   policy = templatefile("policy.tpl", { env = local.workspaceValues })

Comment: @Developer404 The policy is correct. Are you absolutely sure that what you posted in the question is your real template? If so, why would you pass region and account_id into it, and never use it?

Comment: Initially used region and account , now it is removed...

Comment: @Developer404 Then I don't know. The policy generated by my answer is a valid and correct policy. It does not have any strange nor incorrect characters.

Comment: I just noticed from your code, there is no double quotes near jsonencode. Well, the editor was highlighting error so I have been trying with quotes. Inspite of editor error, I tried to execute it is working. Hope this helps someone. VS Code editor shud be updated :-D

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution to avoid this all together is to recreate the policy using the data component "aws_iam_policy_document" and then pass it to the aws_iam_policy resource like the following,

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "example" {
  statement {
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = [
      "ec2:*"
    ]

    resources = [
      "*"
    ]

    condition {
      test     = "ForAllValues:StringLikeIfExists"
      variable = "aws:ResourceTag/Environment"

      values = local.workspaceValues
    }
  }


}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "example" {
  name   = "example_policy"
  path   = "/"
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.example.json
}
```